# Can I use AppleScript to delete files on NAS listed in a file?

Tags: applescript

I am cleaning up my iTunes folders. I realized that there are more than 3k of files which are actually not in iTunes. I identified them and I have all of them inside a text file called "untitled.txt" in the format below.

```
/Volumes/Multimedia/Music/ITunes Media/Kiko/Come On Up/Come On Up.mp3
/Volumes/Multimedia/Music/ITunes Media/Kiko/Traxxxx/Traxxxx.mp3
```

The files are sitting on my NAS so my question would be what would the script look like and will it read the NAS file format (I think it is `ext4`).

Comment: Did you try iTunes' 'consolidate' function? [I've never tested it on a NAS] ..or do you mean they're not listed at all in iTunes, but are simply 'spare files'?

Comment: Not at all in iTunes, just in the iTunes folder... some sort of legacy which I am cleaning up at the moment. I would need the script and then hope it will delete the files.

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and don't forget to take the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using **AppleScript**, it is so much easier just to do it in **Terminal** using `bash`, e.g.:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo rm "$line"; done < /path/to/untitled.txt
```

Run it as is with the `echo` *command* to have a look<sup>1</sup>  at its output, and if it look okay, then run the *command* again without `echo` in it.

Note that when run without the `echo` *command*, the *path file names* will be quoted, so while with `echo` *command* will show as e.g.:

```
rm /Volumes/Multimedia/Music/ITunes Media/Kiko/Come On Up/Come On Up.mp3
```

However, without the `echo` *command*, the `rm` *command* with the *path file names* will *execute* as e.g.:

```
rm "/Volumes/Multimedia/Music/ITunes Media/Kiko/Come On Up/Come On Up.mp3"
```

Thus handling *path file names* that contains *spaces*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hint: Enlarge the window in **Terminal** so you see the full line without it wrapping on the screen as this will make it easier to see any anomalies, if any.

Answer (score 3):

However, if you do prefer to use an **AppleScript** solution, this following **AppleScript** code should do the trick.

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
set filePathsTextFile to "/path/to/untitled.txt"

set posixFiles to readFile(filePathsTextFile)

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with i in posixFiles
        try
            set thisItem to i as POSIX file as alias
            delete thisItem
        on error errMsg number errNum
            activate
            display alert "Cannot Locate File To Be Deleted" message ¬
                errMsg & "  Error Code. " & errNum & linefeed & linefeed ¬
                & "Please Make Sure The Volume Containing File To Be Deleted Is Mounted Or File Exists" as ¬
                critical buttons {"OK"} giving up after 10
            return
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

on readFile(filePathsTextFile)
    set theFile to filePathsTextFile
    set theParagraphs to read theFile as text using delimiter linefeed
end readFile
```